# GXT 2.3.1 Cannot read property 'style' of null on google chrome version 48

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, gxt

> SEVERE: LogConfiguration: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'style' of null

I keep getting this kind of error on the chrome build 48. It can't be produced on Firefox. I am using GXT 2.3.1 for my application. It happens when there is a grid which has hidden column(s). Does anyone has experienced on this issue?

**Additional information**.
As I going through the application, I noticed another exception which I think related to this.

> SEVERE: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'getHeight_21_g$' of nullcom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'getHeight_21_g$' of null

**Full stacktrace** here. [chrome 48 gxt 2.3.1a-gwt22 exception](https://gist.github.com/alifhaikal88/40506cc0dcbc3094b3d7)

**Full source code** here [Source code](https://github.com/alifhaikal88/gxt-chrome48)

Comment: Code that causes this? Stack trace that you get from this?

Comment: So far I've seen this in a ticket, which I think is the same post. https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/8f1dff0310d1c58ca231

Comment: I've seen two issues with the same exception, I'm not sure what's going on yet. I'm drilling the issue further.

Comment: I've found another exception. Maybe it's related. [chrome 48 gxt 2.3.1a-gwt22 exception](https://gist.github.com/alifhaikal88/40506cc0dcbc3094b3d7)

Comment: @ColinAlworth I added stacktrace and the full source code that produce related exception

Comment: Specifically, for me, I had this issue with BufferView.  I had to setForceFit and setAutoFill both to false and it went away.  But yes, this was plaguing my application when Chrome 48 dropped.  And, because I have a large application, I have a sinking feeling this isn't the last time I'll see that exception

Comment: should I wait for chrome team to solve this issue? I believe this isn't gxt bug.

Comment: Almost certainly a Chrome thing, haven't seen it in other browsers (and I've tried).

Answer (score 2):

Also ran into this issue. Janky workaround seems to be to go into the gxt source code and to add the following statements to ColumnHeader.java. So far this has resolved any of my issues that I was experiencing.

Wrap the adjustCellWidth function at line 1000 with this if statement.

```
if(cell != null) { //rest of existing func code in here}
```

At line 1038 change the conditional check to...

```
if (head != null && !head.isRendered() && head.getElement() != null) continue;
```

At line 1075 change the conditional check to...

```
if (head.isRendered() && head.el() != null && head.el().getParent() != null)
```

Again this is most likely a temporary workaround, but it seems to address the issues for the moment.

Comment: Yes! Just for a temporary solution. I had patched the jar for testing purpose. For now, I am going to ask my client to use Firefox until chrome patch release

Comment: Have you filed a bug with Chrome?

Comment: I've written a workaround with Harrison's directions. https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/d14f18eadcd2e45c0f18

Comment: Nope. I didn't file a bug to chrome.